# Using nested cases

Tags: sql-server

What I had tried to do was…

- for any text in column ‘phase’ where it is not ‘Pros’ or ‘SM’ than do the following:

  - calculate the date difference (in number of months) between today’s date and ‘estart’ date. If the number is over 36 than make it equal 36.
  - For text in the column ‘phase’ that are ‘Pros’ or ‘SM’ than make the value equal to the value already in column ‘col1’
- name the new column ‘col12’

```
SELECT pbs, phase, project_name,scoping_start,col1
      ,CASE
                     WHEN phase <> 'Pros' OR phase <> 'SM'  THEN
                                  (CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(m, GETDATE() ,MIN(estart)))>36 THEN 36 ELSE (CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(m, GETDATE() ,MIN(estart))))
                     ELSE col1 END AS col12 
 FROM scheduledates
 GROUP BY pbs, phase, project_name,scoping_start,col1
```

Comment: your nested statements are missing an 'end'

Comment: What's the point of `WHEN phase <> 'Pros' OR phase <> 'SM'  THEN`? Phase will always be different than at least one option so that will always be true.